# search with multiple parameters, java collection choice advise

Tags: java, android, collections, generic-collections

What data structure should I use in the case described below:

I have a simple bean:

```
 public class Points { 

    private String name; 
    private String address; 
    private int phone; 
    private int coord1; 
    private int coord2; 

    //getters+setters 

    }
```

I would like to create several beans and store them in some sort of data structure. 
And be able to search with two parameters - name and address.

For example, user types in "7"  - and it gives him back several object, 
which name or address contains this character?

What data structure should i use and how do i search through it?

If it is important, I actually need this to implement into my android app - 
i would like to search through my points on the map
Also I do not want to create a database so far, as there are only 20 of them.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try java's collection, e.g. hashmap. Although I ran this on PC, for 10000 items, with search
returned 3440 results, it took 76ms.

```
    class Points {

        String name;
        String address;
        int phone;
        int coord1;
        int coord2;

        // getters+setters
    };

    class PointsIdentifier {

        private String name;
        private String address;

        public PointsIdentifier(String name, String address) {
            this.name = name;
            this.address = address;

        }

        public boolean contains(String seq) {
            return name.contains(seq) || address.contains(seq);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Points other = (Points) obj;
            return name.equals(other.name) && address.equals(other.address);
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return name.hashCode() + address.hashCode();
        }
    };

    class PointsCollection {
        private Map<PointsIdentifier, Points> map;

        public PointsCollection() {
            map = new HashMap<PointsIdentifier, Points>();
        }

        public void add(Points p) {
            map.put(new PointsIdentifier(p.name, p.address), p);
        }

        public List<Points> findIdsContaining(String seq) {
            List<Points> resultList = new ArrayList<Points>();
            for (Entry<PointsIdentifier, Points> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getKey().contains(seq)) {
                    resultList.add(entry.getValue());
                }
            }
            // optionally cache result
            return resultList;
        }
    }

    public class Question_11881630 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            PointsCollection places = createCollection(10000);
            System.out.println("Collection created");
        String seq = "1";

        System.out.format("Searching for: \"%s\"\n", seq);
        List<Points> verifySearch = verifySearch(places, seq);
        //show(verifySearch);
    }

    private static void show(List<Points> verifySearch) {
        int i = 1;
        for (Points p : verifySearch) {
            System.out.println(i + ": " + p.name + ", " + p.address);
            i++;
        }
    }

    private static List<Points> verifySearch(PointsCollection places, String seq) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        List<Points> searchResult = places.findIdsContaining(seq);
        System.out.println("Search results: " + searchResult.size());
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Operation time: " + formatTime(end - start));
        return searchResult;
    }

    private static String formatTime(long elapsed) {
        return elapsed + " miliseconds";
    }

    private static PointsCollection createCollection(int number) {
        PointsCollection coll = new PointsCollection();
        while (number > 0) {
            coll.add(createSamplePoint(number));
            number--;
        }
        return coll;
    }

    private static Points createSamplePoint(int number) {
        Points p = new Points();
        p.name = "VeryVeryLongName: " + number;
        p.address = "VeryVeryLongLongAddress: " + number;
            p.coord1 = 123;
            p.coord2 = 456;
            return p;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect! thank you very much! do you use any tools to check how much time it took to run such a code?

Comment: @tania: Depending on your data size and how many times you are going to execute this op, this solution is very inefficient (extremely slower then a clever data-structure). Each query requires iterating the entire collection, which is a terrible solution for large data, but simple and does the trick for small data.

Comment: @amit yes, i've only 20 entries or so.. max 40, so should not be a big deal

Comment: @tania: In this case I would keep it as simple as possible, and take this approach. Just remember that if your data grows larger over time - this should be the first thing you will need to refactor. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

A **[trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)** seems a good fit. It is an efficient data structure to find all strings with a certain prefix.

If you want to use one of the existing java collections instead, you can use a [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), and its [`floor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#floor%28E%29) method to get the element before the needed prefix - and then start iterating the set while it still matches.

**If you are looking for search by substring**, and not only prefix - you might want to use a **[suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree)** instead.

An (inefficient) alternative that uses java's existing containers - is to store all substrings of your keys in a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) or a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), but it will require quadric amount of space.

Comment: are there any implementations of suffix tree in java?

Comment: @tania: I never tried it, but the wikipedia article links to [this implementation](http://en.literateprograms.org/File:Suffix-tree-rendered-output.png). However, from reading the summary - it seems to be an inefficient implementation.